# How to add new key value pair into existing object

Tags: jquery, object

I have a simple function:

```
function pagination(opt, limit){
    console.log(opt);
    //logs out this-> [Object { limit="2",  layout="getConversations"}]

    if (typeof opt === 'object') {
        var list = {
            data: [opt]
        }
        list.data['limitstart'] = 24; //undefined
        console.debug(data); //here it should list three key value pairs including limitstart which just added
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
list.data.push({ 'limitstart': 24 }); //creates another object.
```

expected output:

```
[Object { limit="2",  layout="getConversations", limitstart=24}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it as string, as in your example, but as you put the object in an array with `[obj]`, you have to select the index `0` too:

```
list.data[0]["limitstart"] = 24;
```

Or you can do it as a property:

```
list.data[0].limitstart = 24;
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/hsqc7jow/2/)**

For your exprected output you don't have to put the `obj` in an array:

```
var obj = {limit: '2', layout: 'getConversations'};
var list = {data: obj};

list.data.limitstart = 24;
console.debug(list.data); // you have to log 'list.data' not 'data'
```

Comment: it works, could you please explain , why must use [0]?

Comment: Because you put the `obj` inside an array with `[obj]` (*the `[]` around will do this*). Because `obj` is the first entry in that new array, you have to select the `obj` by index `0`. @Keren

Answer (score 2):

To get the output as you require you don't need to place `opt` in to an array, you simply need to add a property to it, like this:

```js
function pagination(opt, limit) {
  console.log('input', opt);

  if (typeof opt === 'object') {
    opt.limitstart = 24; // add the property here
  }

  console.log('output', opt);
}

pagination({
  limit: '2',
  layout: 'getConversations'
});
```